# scp cannot transfer file?

Tags: ssh, scp

This problem is i cannot transfer file from my computer to server.

I use command scp -v ./1.cap ug01:/cshome/twu5/, it take about 3 mintus, but scp did nothing. Then i terminal the scp.
Here is the debug log.

```
tyw@CosHiM-MAC:~|⇒  scp -v ./1.cap ug01:/cshome/twu5/
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host ug01, user (unspecified), command scp -v -t /cshome/twu5/
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/tyw/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/tyw/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/tyw/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for ug01
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/tyw/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/tyw/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/tyw/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/tyw/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 5a:3b:67:99:9d:e1:fe:d0:38:fc:ce:81:b1:c6:57:83
debug1: Host 'ug01.cs.ualberta.ca' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/tyw/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/tyw/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /cshome/twu5/
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
^Cdebug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Killed by signal 2.
```

Comment: The ssh is work fine, and i an transfer file my laptop and other servers.    This file is only 30kb.

Comment: When you ssh into this server, is it doing any unusual output when you log in compared to your other servers?  If the server is outputting something like a message of the day on login, this would confuse scp.